# Deformation of a Liouville form with a diffeotopy

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a surface with boundary and let $f_t: M \to M, t \in [0,1]$ be a differentiable family of diffeomorphisms (I think this is usually called a diffeotopy). Suppose I have a Liouville form $\lambda_0 \in \Omega_1(M)$ such that $f_0$ is exact, i.e. $f_0^*\lambda_0 - \lambda_0 = dF$ for some function $F: M \to \mathbb{R}$. Is it always possible to find a differentiable family of Liouville forms $\lambda_t$ such that $f_t$ is exact for all $t \in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is not true. For a function to be exact, it needs to preserve the symplectic form $d\lambda$. This puts strong conditions on the function, for instance it's differential should have determinant $1$ at fixed points. This is clearly not preserved in a diffeotopy.